# How to hide elements from the form editor

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, element

so I'm making a chat room, and it has several different scenes. However, for maximum efficiency, I need to have a clean workspace. However, the start here:
[First scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iopTE.png). Is hard to have in the background when I'm placing stuff around. I know how to hide it once it runs, but is there any way to keep it alive, but invisible when I'm editing?

Comment: In your mind, what is the difference between hiding it and make it invisible?  Please read [ask] and take the [tour[

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is no that possibility but there are 3 others (second one i do not prefer and would NEVER use but it is possible)

So you want to hide some elements in editing process because you are doing something behind them. From picture i see that first one is some kind of login form. So these are solutions:

**1. Creating another form**

So most common and practical is creating another form.

- Simply create form with right click on your solution explorer > new > Windows Form
- Then call it with buttons

Calling:

```
NewForm nf = new NewForm();
nf.Show();
this.Close();
```

**2. Temporary moving it off**

So idea is to move controls to the side in editing mode and then when you run program you set their location by code with simply doing `button1.Location = new Point(15, 15);`

**3. Using TabPage**

Create TabPage with 3 tabs.

First one are buttons, Second is if user want to create third if want to join.

Add this to your tab so it looks better and have no buttons at top (to user swich tabs)

```
tabControl.Appearance = TabAppearance.FlatButtons;
tabControl.ItemSize = new Size(0, 1);
tabControl.SizeMode = TabSizeMode.Fixed;
```

Then on button go to specific tab and boom.